# Why can't I post a form field with 'status' in the name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, browser, parameters

Edit - clearly no-one has any idea what is vexing me here. I think it's just a matter of there being something that I've done elsewhere in the page that's blocking the status attribute being sent. The problem is I just can't see anything. I'm hoping someone has seen something similar and can suggest where I need to look.

---

I have a dummy form on my page to post data to my web-app. It is created in Rails (using HAML) like so;

```
=form_tag bulk_invoice_path(''), method: 'put', class: 'mark-sent-form' do
  =hidden_field_tag 'invoice[status]', 'Sent'
```

This generates the following html;

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/bulk_invoices/" class="mark-sent-form" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="OU8GtbHycR/EJ+H3GG9MN59xI59v47LSaFc2wYZloAs=" />
  </div>
  <input id="invoice_status" name="invoice[status]" type="hidden" value="Sent" />
</form>
```

In the DOM, this appears as follows

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/bulk_invoices/" class="mark-sent-form" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="OU8GtbHycR/EJ+H3GG9MN59xI59v47LSaFc2wYZloAs=">
  </div>
  <input id="invoice_status" name="invoice[status]" type="hidden" value="Sent">
</form>
```

This form is posted with jquery (using coffeescript) like so;

```
jQuery ->
  $('a.mark-sent').click -> updateBulkInvoices('.mark-sent-form')

updateBulkInvoices = (form) ->
  $(form).attr('action', "/bulk_invoices/#{checkedInvoices().get().join()}").submit()
```

This pattern has served me well with other actions but the 'invoice[status]' seems to be causing problems. When the form is submitted with jQuery the hidden field is not passed. I see the following in my Rails console;

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+qW9kIih5l2j69w1LK2YfQ9mYQ7nKPDm5XgLZuKB4ic=", "id"=>"16"}
```

i.e. the invoice[status] field isn't being passed with the form parameters. If I change the name of this field to anything else it works just fine, e.g.

```
=form_tag bulk_invoice_path(''), method: 'put', class: 'mark-sent-form' do
  =hidden_field_tag 'invoice[flatus]', 'sent'
```

gives me the following parameters in my console;

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+qW9kIih5l2j69w1LK2YfQ9mYQ7nKPDm5XgLZuKB4ic=", "invoice"=>{"flatus"=>"sent"}, "id"=>"16"}
```

I see the same thing happening if I monitor the 'network' tab on Chrome's developer tools so I don't think it's a Rails thing, it seems to be a browser issue. I get the same thing with Safari and Firefox as well though.

Is status some sort of magical reserved word in browser forms? What's going on here?

Comment: No there is no such reserved words I tried it and its working fine

Comment: OK, it's not working for me though.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML form?

Comment: If it isn't showing up in the network tab, then it's a form issue. Can you post the form html from the source, and from the DOM?

Comment: Any chance you're using the same plugin/extension in all your browsers?  The fact that it works for Aayush, but not you suggests you've got something special going on... try disabling all Chrome's extensions to see if something there is intercepting it.

Comment: Have you checked the rendered HTML? Is the hidden field rendered correctly in the first place? Also, check any other JavaScript you may include for potentially modifying a field with 'status' in the name or id.

Comment: I've posted the form html from the source and the DOM as requested above. Great idea about the extensions, unfortunately I disabled all of them and it still doesn't work. I have a lot of javascript on my page but I can't see that any of it is affecting this. Is there a way of seeing what javascript is run after I trigger the submit?

Comment: you should be able to set a breakpoint in the Sources view of Chrome dev tools.  Find the accordian pane for "Event Listener Breakpoints" at the bottom right.  Under "Mouse" should be "click".  Under "Control" should be "submit". Check whichever you'd think will be helpful and you should be able to intercept the form send.

Comment: also note a shortcut to disabling all your extensions in chrome is to open a new window in "incognito" mode.  this will have extensions blocked by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not been able to reproduce the problem, but I suspect it is being caused by the Javascript when submitting the form.  To debug this, you can do the following:

1. Open the page in Chrome
2. Right click the submit button, choose 'inspect element'
3. select the 'sources' tab.
4. In the sources tab, find the source for the Javascript being called
   when you click submit.  You will probably have to click on the
   teensy right arrow in the box beneath the 'elements' tab.  Also, if
   the code has been uglified with all the line breaks removed, you can
   click on the 'pretty print' curly braces icon at the bottom of the
   page.
5. Once you find the method, click on the line number next to it on the
   left.  In the right pane you should see it appear under the
   "Breakpoints" section.
6. Reload the page
7. Click the submit button.

This should bring you into the Javascript debugger paused on the submit action and you can  then step through the code and see exactly what it is doing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This prompted me to finally step through my code properly and I discovered a function with the same name as the one I was calling. I had written it ages ago, replaced it, not deleted it and forgotten about it. Anyway, it was the culprit for my form not being submitted properly. This project has more Javascript than I've ever written before and I'm starting to lose track. I think I need some tips on Javascript wrangling!